# Laravel Backpack with FullCalendar issue

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, laravel-backpack

I'm using Laravel Backpack 4.1 for my project. On my Dashboard page I'm using several jQuery plugins such as:

- bootstrap-daterangepicker
- select2

They are working fine for me.

Now I want to empliment FullCalendar jQuery plugin. All I want to do is showing calendar events. The problem is that controls are not working in the calendar (I can not switch between months, can not switch betwee layouts (month, week, day) etc.). If calenrad events are in the current month the are displayd properly.

No any errors on browser console.

I'm using this plugin in my another project (Lalavel, but not Backpack) and everything is OK.

By the way, jQuery plugin ChartJs not working too and not generates any console errors (charts appears for a second and disapperars).

May it be conflicts with enternal Backpack's js-files? Has anyone met this problem?

My pretty simple view file (*resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/dashboard.blade.php*):

```
@extends(backpack_view('blank'))

@section('content')
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4>Bookings calendar</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div id='calendar'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('after_styles')
    <link href="{{ asset('packages/fullcalendar/main.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@endsection

@section('after_scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('packages/fullcalendar/main.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialDate: "2022-03-01",
                events: {!! $bookingsForCalendar !!}
            });

            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT**: the reason is my VueJS application. Question can by closed.

Comment: I've used both FullCalendar and ChartJS inside Backpack pages soo... I don't think there's any conflict between them... Are you sure you don't have any custom scripts that might interfere? Also, have you pushed fullcalendar to "before_scripts" or "after_scripts"? The second one is better, since then you're sure you have jQuery and everything.

Comment: @tabacitu, Hello! Thanks for your work! I've updated my question. Now, as I write this text, I remembered that my application has parts in VueJS. Perhaps they affect. I have to check

Comment: @tabacitu, yes, the reason of my problem is my VueJS app. Sorry, thank you for answer. Good luck!